# Update Question > 14.04 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, updates

I just got an Ubuntu laptop from an eBay seller. Currently running 14.04, I ran the software updater twice, was expecting to be "automatically" upgraded/updated to 15.04, but this did not happen.

So either I'm doing something wrong or I'm wrong about how the update/release/upgrade process works.

Do I really need or want to upgrade to 15.04? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a dupe @hg8 , it seems more of a 'should I upgrade?' question than a 'how to upgrade?' question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend sticking with 14.04 LTS.

The LTS stands for Long Term Support, which means that issues with software and security vulnerabilities will be fixed and maintained for 5 years, so until April 2019.

The next LTS release will be in April 2016, otherwise the standard support period is 9 months. So if you chose 15.04, you'd ideally want to move to 15.10 before the end of January 2016. More info about the release schedule for Ubuntu can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).

There may be new features in newer releases, and they are likely to support newer hardware, but an LTS is more likely to be stable for longer.

I think there's a 'move to new release' option in the software updater somewhere if you're set on the upgrade, but I don't tend to use the GUI for updating so can't point you there more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 14.04 is an LTS -- Long Term Support -- release.  As such, it will be serviced at least until the next LTS verion is released (likely 16.04, based on past history).  Given support expires much more quickly (one year from release, as I recall) for non-LTS versions, if you don't want to upgrade every few months, you may want to stick with 14.04 for the time being.  IMO, you don't need to upgrade at 15.04 unless there's a feature change you consider important.

Comment: So basically, I should just trust the Software Updater and not worry about it for now, because I'll get an auto update in April 2016?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Update Manager" . I'm such a newbie

Comment: I don't believe the update will be automatic -- there's a process spelled out in the Ubuntu web site for upgrading without a clean reinstall -- but yes, trusting the "update manager" is what I'm currently doing on two computers.  The system is kept as secure as current development allows, and the interface doesn't change until I do a version upgrade.